# Overlapping inside listview li

Tags: jquery, listview, overlapping

I generate list items inside a listview dynamically (onclick). You can view my code here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Zcj/17/)

Since I have to accompany the jsfiddle link with code, here goes:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">Select option:
    <br>
    <select name="prodselect" id="prodselect">
        <option data-foo="xxx">first</option>
        <option data-foo="yyy" selected="selected">Second</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="appeprod" id="appeprod" value="Add option" data-icon="add" data-inline="true" />
</div>
<ul name="listaproduse" id="listaproduse" data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="e" data-count-theme="b" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">
         <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Selected options</h3>
 <span class="ui-li-count">5</span> 
    </li>
    <li id="produsele" name="produsele"></li>
</ul>
```

**and jscript**

```
$('#appeprod').click(function() {
    var option = $('#prodselect').val();
    var box = document.getElementById('prodselect');
    var option2 = box.options[box.selectedIndex].text;
    $('#listaproduse').append('<li><h3>'+option2+'<h3><p>'+option+'</p><p>Some comment:</p></li>');
    $('#listaproduse').listview("refresh");
});
```

My problem is (as you can see it in jsfiddle) the H3 tag content overlaps the bellow paragraph.

I updated the jsfiddle , added below the dynamic listview, a static one with the same content that I desire to generate in the dynamic one. The static one looks fine while the dynamic one is overlapping. What can I do?
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the `<h3>` properly in your JS code.
Should be: `<h3>'+option2+'</h3>`

Comment: Wow.. **I AM** tired afterall... You are right. The lack of / in the closing tag did it. The changed and working code is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3Zcj/18/) (I just love to find code when I am looking for something so the least I can do is contribute with this for other beginners like me). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the style. I looked at the styling added to that element and found that the margin-top was -0.5em

**CSS**

```
.ui-li-desc
{
 margin-top: 0;
}
```